# SSRS report giving error for multivalue parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I have declared a multi value parameter in my SSRS report. The parameter is "Team" and it has multiple values i text like: "All", "HY", "DFI", "CRS", etc.
Now i am using this parameter to show or hide various columns in my report.

For example, or one of the columns , the visibility works as follows:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Team.Value = "HY", True,False) Or IIF(Parameters!Team.Value = "EQ", True,False) Or IIF(Parameters!Team.Value = "GL", True,False) Or IIF(Parameters!Team.Value = "CRS", True,False)
```

The report works okay as long as I select one value from the parameter dropdown. But I wanted to select more than one value, so i clicked "Allow multiple values" under the Parameter Properties. Upon doing that and running the report, I get the following error:

> The Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix2’ contains an error:
>   Overload resolution failed because no Public '=' can be called with
>   these arguments:
>       'Public Shared Operator =(a As String, b As String) As Boolean':
>           Argument matching parameter 'a' cannot convert from 'Object()' to 'String'. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

How can I resolve this error?

Update: The error is resolved now. But the displaying of combined columns, which was the purpose behind adding multiple values in the parameter is still not resolved, when I select more than one team in the dropdown, eg. "DFI" and "HY', then instead of displaying columns for both, the report hides columns for both teams.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your team parameter allows multiple values to be selected, `Parameters!Team.Value` becomes an array object.  This means you cannot make a comparison `Parameters!Team.Value = "aString"` because they are incomparable types.

In order to achieve the result you want, you would have to change your `Parameters!Team.Value = "aString"` calls to `Join(Parameters!Team.Value,",").contains("aString")`.

The `Join` Function returns an Object array delimited by the specified string.

Example: `Join(Parameters!Team.Value,",")` Can return `"HY,EQ,GL"`

For each set of columns, you will need to set the visibility for each team where it is set to `False` where you don't want columns hidden.

For you columns with "DF" or "All" selected:

```
=IIF(Join(Parameters!Team.Value,",").Contains("DF") OR Join(Parameters!Team.Value,",").Contains("ALL"), False,True)
```

For columns with "HY" or "All" selected:

```
=IIF(Join(Parameters!Team.Value,",").Contains("HY") OR Join(Parameters!Team.Value,",").Contains("ALL"), False,True)
```

For columns with "EQ" or "All" selected:

```
 =IIF(Join(Parameters!Team.Value,",").Contains("EQ") OR Join(Parameters!Team.Value,",").Contains("ALL"), False,True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Martin. I didn't try with Join yet but the previous solution didn't give the correct result

Comment: @himanshumalik Yeah I realized I made a mistake with my previous solution.  The previous one didn't work because `Parameters!Team.Value.toString()' would have just returned "Object []" instead of something like "HY,EQ".  I hope this one works well for you :)

Comment: So the error which I mentioned in my original post is definitely gone, so thanks for that:) The solution which you provided works for individual team, i.e. if I select one team in the dropdown. But it doesn't works for more than one team. For eg. if I select both "DFI" and "HY" in the dropdown, the report hides columns for both of them...

Comment: For clarification, how many columns are you using the visibility condition?  Which ones need to be hidden for when teams?  Eg. if you select multiple teams, are you trying to hide individual columns for each team?

Comment: So, I am using around 12 columns with these conditions. 2 columns need to be visible for "DFI" and "All" only, 5 columns for "HY" and "All", and 5 columns for "EQ" and "All". What I am trying to achieve is if I select both "DFI" and "HY", then I should able to see the 5 columns of HY and 2 columns of DFI and the columns for EQ are hidden and so on for other teams combo too. But I think the hidden column condition is overpowering the visible columns and upon selecting multiple teams, columns for both teams get hidden...

Comment: It sounds like the condition is hiding/showing more than it should.  I can update my solution to fix the condition but you should update your question to include that information so that it is complete ^^

Comment: Ok will do that

Comment: @himanshumalik I added the conditions that may help, please let me know how this works out.  I flipped the logic between "False" and "True" because you don;t want it to hide if the parameters contains the team, right?

Comment: Martin I hope you don't mind I have made some changes to your solution. The original Iif... OR Iif... produces True unless the user selects both ALL and the Team

Comment: @MartinNavarro and niktrs The edited solution provided by niktrs worked exactly right. Thank you so much guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Remember the "hidden" property is True when the column is hidden, and False when it's shown. You can use the Array.IndexOf function to look for a specific value selected in the multi-value parameter, and set each team's column like this (this is team HY):

```
=IIF(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Team.Value, "HY") > -1, False, True)
```

In English: "If you find HY as a selected parameter value, do not hide this column, otherwise hide it."

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this solution did not work as expected. Actually I wanted both the team and "All" to display a particular team's columns. So i separate the expressions by OR. For eg. : =IIF(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Team.Value, "HY") > -1, False, True) OR =IIF(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!Team.Value, "All") > -1, False, True). But this doesn't displays the correct result. Also if I replace True with False i.e. reverse the condition and use opposite teams then on selecting the checkbox "DFI" and "HY", the columns of both the teams get hidden.